# Get a datatable value to another datatable

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, datatable

I want to get id value from one datatable(1) to another datatable(2). Datatable(1) has a button called assign in the actions column when it clicks a bootstrap modal open with the datatable(2). When that datatable, each row has a check box in the actions column. I want, when a user checks a checkbox it needs to appear the id of the relevant raw of datatable(1), in a bootstrap badge. How can I do it?

this is the render method in datatable(2),

```
render: function (data, type, full, meta,) 
{
let name = data['name']

return '<input type="checkbox" id="emp_checkbox" value="'+name+'" name="emp[]"> <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">'[here i want to display raw id of datatable(1)]'</button>'       
}
```

my first datatable:

[image]

When user click a assign button, second datatable will appear:

[image]

Comment: can you calrify with screenshots?

Comment: I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using javascript onchange event on checkbox

```
render: function (data, type, full, meta,) 
{
let name = data['name'], id = data['id'];

return '<input type="checkbox" id="emp_checkbox" value="'+name+'" name="emp[]" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = this.checked ? \''+id+'\' : \'\' "> <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm"></button>'       
}
```